# What happens TECHNICALLY i.e. what all files are generated (with extensions) when we Compile-Build-Deploy a Java Project?

Tags: java, deployment, build, compilation

What happens TECHNICALLY i.e.

- What all files are generated (with extensions) when we Compile-Build-Deploy a Java Project ?
- Can anyone please highlight the differences in the above terms - Compilation vs Build vs Deploying. (in terms of a Java Project mentioning the significance of a jar file, a war and jws file)

Can anyone explain this wrt JDeveloper and WebLogicServer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building vs. Compiling (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650168/building-vs-compiling-java)

Comment: @XeshanJ yeah, Easier said than done
but guess what! that's not the answer.